# reverse proxy for multiple websites

Tags: apache, weblogic, reverse-proxy, virtualhost, httpd.conf

Initially, I have installed two Weblogic application servers on my network with the first WebLogic on IP address 192.168.0.201(hostname firstserver.example.com)
and second Weblogic server on IP address 192.168.0.202(hostname secondserver.example.com)
I have installed apache server on my oracle virtual box(to configure the reverse proxy for testing purpose)

Initially, I have configured  reverse proxy for one application server
I have configured reverse proxy like this
httpd.conf

```html
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName www.firstserver.com
     ServerAlias firstserver.com
     ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
     TransferLog /var/log/httpd/access_log

     <Location /console/>
    ProxyPass  http://firstserver.example.com:7001/console/ retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse   http://firstserver.example.com:7001/console/
   
     </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

It worked perfectly when I entered following address on browser(www.firstserver.com/console/).

I have entered following details in the host file

```html
    192.168.0.201 firstserver.example.com   firstserver
    192.168.0.202 secondserver.example.com   secondserver
```

When I tried to reverse proxy two application servers

I have tried with different settings in httpd.conf like

```html
Listen 192.168.0.201:80
Listen 192.168.0.202:80
NameVirtualHost 192.168.0.201:80
NameVirtualHost 192.168.0.202:80
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.201:80>
    ServerName www.firstserver.com
     ServerAlias firstserver.com
     ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
     TransferLog /var/log/httpd/access_log

     <Location /console/>
    ProxyPass  http://firstserver.example.com:7001/console/ retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse   http://firstserver.example.com:7001/console/
    
   
     </Location>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.202:80>
    ServerName www.secondserver.com
     ServerAlias secondserver.com
     ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
     TransferLog /var/log/httpd/access_log

     <Location /console/>
    ProxyPass  http://secondserver.com:7001/console/ retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse   http://secondserver.com:7001/console/
    
   
     </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

But didn't worked
Please suggest me the better solution

Comment: 1- if you are using Apache 2.4, no name for NameVirtualHost anymore.  2- split your log files so you can know what is from one virtual host and the other.  3- do you have any logs at all?  Put your LogLevel to trace.  4- have you made sure you can connect from the proxy to both servers on port 7001?  5- your host file has ...example... in the name, yet you do not use that in the Apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Your apache config shows that you misinterpreted the meaning of the "Listen" and "Servername" directives. These should be values that both resolve to the webserver, telling Apache on what IP adress to listen for requests and how to handle any HTTP request that arrives for "www.webserver.com". These should not resolve to the application servers in any way.

If you add a "[ip address of webserver] www.webserver.com" to the hostfile of the machine running the browser, this example would work with your examples:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.webserver.com
     ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
     TransferLog /var/log/httpd/access_log

     <Location /console/>
         ProxyPass  http://firstserver:7001/console/ 
         ProxyPassReverse   http://firstserver:7001/console/
     </Location>
```

Here's a NamedVirtualHost example for if you would have given your webserver a second host file entry ("www.webserver2.com") on the *client*:

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.webserver.com
     ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
     TransferLog /var/log/httpd/access_log

     <Location /console/>
         ProxyPass  http://firstserver:7001/console/ 
         ProxyPassReverse   http://firstserver:7001/console/
     </Location>
   </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.webserver2.com
     ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
     TransferLog /var/log/httpd/access_log

     <Location /console/>
         ProxyPass  http://secondserver:7001/console/ 
         ProxyPassReverse   http://secondserver:7001/console/
     </Location>
   </VirtualHost>
```

This way, from the client you would access www.webserver.com/console and www.webserver2.com/console

Comment: but i want to use multiple virtual hosts for multiple application servers(first server,second server) in that scenario how can we edit httpd.conf file

Comment: I've added an extended example based on more DNS names resolving to the webserver on the browser client PC.